# OpenCvSharp with ZXing read barcodes with camera

Tags: c#, opencv, zxing, zxing.net

I'm having a problem with integrating Zxing libary with openCvSharp. I'm trying to read barcodes live with camera.

It throws an exception at the line `Result result = barcodeReader.Decode(test);` that gives;

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'You have to declare a delegate which converts your byte array to a luminance source object.'
```

I would appreciate If someone have any solution, suggestion or idea!
Full code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);
            LuminanceSource source;

            using (Window window = new Window("Camera"))
                
            using(Mat image = new Mat())
            {

                while (true)
                {
                    capture.Read(image); // same as cvQueryFrame

                    BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

                    var barcodeBitMap = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(image);

                    byte[] test;

                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        barcodeBitMap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        test = stream.ToArray();
                    }

                    Result result = barcodeReader.Decode(test);

                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("result: " + result.Text);
                    }

                    window.ShowImage(image);

                    Cv2.WaitKey(30);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the .Net target platform you can use the bitmap directly with the method Decode. Only the .Net core/standard versions don't support the Bitmap classes directly.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);

        BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

        using (Window window = new Window("Camera"))
        using(Mat image = new Mat())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                capture.Read(image); // same as cvQueryFrame

                var barcodeBitMap = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(image);

                Result result = barcodeReader.Decode(barcodeBitMap);

                if (result != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("result: " + result.Text);
                }

                window.ShowImage(image);

                Cv2.WaitKey(30);
            }
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you can try out one of the following bindings

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.OpenCV/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.OpenCVSharp.V2/

With them you can instantiate another BarcodeReader implementation which supports the Mat struct directly.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);

        BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new ZXing.OpenCV.BarcodeReader();

        using (Window window = new Window("Camera"))
        using(Mat image = new Mat())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                capture.Read(image); // same as cvQueryFrame

                Result result = barcodeReader.Decode(image);

                if (result != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("result: " + result.Text);
                }

                window.ShowImage(image);

                Cv2.WaitKey(30);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm using .NET Core 3.1, and OpenCvSharp4. Using the bindings maked things clearlier for me, but now I'm facing another exception when trying to debug the code. `System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'Void OpenCvSharp.VideoCapture..ctor(Int32, OpenCvSharp.VideoCaptureAPIs)'.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

`

Comment: Remove all ZXing stuff, only try to capture an image and show it. Does the exception still occur?

Comment: Yes, exception still occurs after removing all ZXing stuff.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of OpenCvSharp v4? Perhaps do you reference different versions? Zxing bindings only support v3 at the moment. Perhaps you have two different assembly references in your project?
https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/868